# I am trying to write a program that allows a user to input a series of exam scores as integers

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program that allows a user to input a series of exam scores as integers.

I want the outputs to look something like:

Enter an integer, or -99 to quit: 80

Enter an integer, or -99 to quit: 95

Enter an integer, or -99 to quit: 65

Enter an integer, or -99 to quit: -99

Largest: 95
Smallest: 65

2nd run:

Enter an integer, or -99 to quit: -99

You did not enter any numbers.

I got the first part down, but I cant seem to find out how to get the "You did not enter any numbers" line when I enter -99.

This is what I have so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;    // Needed for the Scanner class

/**
   This program shows the largest and smallest exam scores. The user
   enters a series of exam scores, then -99 when finished.
   UPDATED to show even number of points using if-statement
*/

public class Grades
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      int score = 0;       // Exam score
      int min = 100;       // Hold smallest score
      int max = 0;         // Hold largest score

      // Create a Scanner object for keyboard input.
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

      // Display general instructions.
      System.out.println("Enter an integer, or -99 to quit: ");
      System.out.println();

      // Get the first exam score.
      System.out.print("Enter an integer, or -99 to quit: ");
      score = keyboard.nextInt();

      // Input exam scores until -99 is entered.
      while (score != -99)
      {
         // Add points to totalPoints.
         if (score > max)
            max = score;
         if (score < min)
            min = score;
         // Get the next number of points.
         System.out.print("Enter an integer, or -99 to quit: ");
         score = keyboard.nextInt();
      }

      // Display the largest and smallest score.
      System.out.println("Largest: " + max);
      System.out.println("Smallest: " + min);
   }
}
```

Comment: after the loop and after the output reset your variables to `-99`, then after the loop before the output check if the variavles are still `-99`

Answer (score 1):

What about introducing a variable which counts the entered numbers and is increased in the while loop?

OR as an alternative you could check after your while loop if the numbers changed:

```
if(min > max) {
    System.out.println("You did not enter any numbers.");
}
else {
    System.out.println("Largest: " + max);
    System.out.println("Smallest: " + min);
}
```

This would work because at the beginning you initialize the the `min` variable to `100` and the `max` variable to `0` which would result `true` for the `min > max` check if no numbers were entered.

Answer (score 1):

The following code don't work when you enter 0 & 100:

```
if (max = 0 && min = 100)
    System.out.println("You did not enter any numbers");
else{
    System.out.println("Largest: " + max);
    System.out.println("Smallest: " + min);
}
```

It is good option to use additional boolean variable to check any input diferrent than -99:

```
public class Grades
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int score = 0;       // Exam score
        int min = 100;       // Hold smallest score
        int max = -100;         // Hold largest score
        boolean isAnyScore = false;

        // Create a Scanner object for keyboard input.
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Display general instructions.
        System.out.print("Enter an integer, or -99 to quit: ");
        System.out.println();

        // Input exam scores until -99 is entered.
        while(true)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter an integer, or -99 to quit: ");
            score = keyboard.nextInt(); //Get the exam score.
            if(score == -99) { break; }
            else { isAnyScore = true; }

            // Add points to totalPoints.
            if (score > max) { max = score; }
            if (score < min) { min = score; }
        }

        // Display the largest and smallest score.
        if(!isAnyScore) { System.out.println("You did not enter any numbers"); }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Largest: " + max);
            System.out.println("Smallest: " + min);
        }
    }
}
```

Variable `isAnyScore` is false. When you enter -99 in first loop run it still will be false, because there are no assign. When you enter something else than -99 in first loop run, it always will be a true (it will be asigned in any loop run as true). When `isAnyScore` is changing from false to true, it always will be the true, because you always assign the true, never false.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your program:

```
if (max == 0 && min == 100)
    System.out.println("You did not enter any numbers");
else{
    System.out.println("Largest: " + max);
    System.out.println("Smallest: " + min);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int score = 0;       // Exam score
    int min = 100;       // Hold smallest score
    int max = 0;         // Hold largest score
    boolean isNumberEntered = false; //Test if any number has been entered.

    // Create a Scanner object for keyboard input.
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Input exam scores until -99 is entered.
    while (score != -99)
    {
        // Get the next number of points.
        System.out.print("Enter an integer, or -99 to quit: ");
        score = keyboard.nextInt();

        if (score == -99) {
            break;
        } else {
            // If the first number is entered
            if (!isNumberEntered)
                isNumberEntered = true;
            // Add points to totalPoints.
            if (score > max)
                max = score;
            if (score < min)
                min = score;
        }


    }

    if (isNumberEntered) {
        // Display the largest and smallest score.
        System.out.println("Largest: " + max);
        System.out.println("Smallest: " + min);
    } else {
        System.out.println("You did not enter any numbers!");
    }

}
```

How about if you try this? Do you want to stay in the loop until one number has been added or is htis the way you want it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the grade is between 100 to 0.So I changed a little. If the input is < 0 and >100 , the output is "You did not enter any numbers".

```
  package chapter5;


import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Grades
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      int min = 100;       // Hold smallest score
      int max = 0;         // Hold largest score

      // Create a Scanner object for keyboard input.
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

      // Display general instructions.
      System.out.print("Enter an integer, or -99 to quit: ");
     int score = keyboard.nextInt();
      if(score<0||score>100){
          System.out.println("You did not enter any numbers.");
      }

      // Input exam scores until -99 is entered.
      if(score>=0||score<=100){
      while (score != -99)
      {
         // Add points to totalPoints.
         if (score > max)
            max = score;
         if (score < min)
            min = score;
         // Get the next number of points.
         System.out.print("Enter an integer, or -99 to quit: ");
         score = keyboard.nextInt();
          if(score==-99){
                System.out.println();}

                else if(score!=-99&&score<0||score>100){
          System.out.println("You did not enter any numbers.");}

         }
      }
      // Display the largest and smallest score.
      System.out.println("Largest: " + max);
      System.out.println("Smallest: " + min);


   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Grades
{
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        int score = 0;       // Exam score
        int min = 100;       // Hold smallest score
        int max = 0;         // Hold largest score
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Display general instructions.
        int i = 1;
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter an integer, or -99 to quit: ");
            score = keyboard.nextInt();
            if (score > max) {
                max = score;
            }
            if (score < min) {
                min = score;
            }
            i++;
            if (i > 5) {
                break;
            }
        } while ((score != -99));

        // Display the largest and smallest score.
        System.out.println("Largest: " + max);
        System.out.println("Smallest: " + min);
    }
}
```